# how import modules in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to import functions from others files in other directory, but take error
ModuleNotFoundError

Test structure:

```
py_path/
    p1/
        __init__.py
        s1.py
    p2/
        __init__.py
        s2.py
    __init__.py
```

py_path/`__init__.py`:

```
from . import p1, p2
```

py_path/p1/`__init__.py`:

```
from s1 import *
```

py_path/p1/`s1.py`:

```
from .p2 import s2
f2()
```

py_path/p2/`__init__.py:`

```
from s2 import *
```

py_path/p2/`s2.py:`

```
def f2():
    print('test func in s2.py')
```

How import module from other file?

Comment: how is your if __name__ == "__main__" ?!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can import  `path` from the `sys module` and add the address of the file you want to use to it. This way you can import module from other files.
I hope that it's useful for you :).

Comment: this is absolutely not what you should be doing.